# Getting Requires: libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit) exception

Tags: dockerfile, centos7, libmagic

am trying to install Install PHP 7.1 on CentOS using docker file,
but looks like some error is always stopping,

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM centos:7

# Install some must-haves
RUN yum -y install vim wget sendmail
RUN yum -y install libtool make automake autoconf nasm libpng-static
RUN yum -y install git
RUN git --version

# Install PHP 7.1 on CentOS
RUN rpm -Uvh https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-7.noarch.rpm \
    && rpm -Uvh https://mirror.webtatic.com/yum/el7/webtatic-release.rpm
    
RUN yum update -y
RUN yum install yum-utils
RUN yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71

RUN yum -y install php71w php71w-bcmath php71w-cli php71w-common php71w-curl php71w-fpm php71w-gd php71w-ldap php71w-imap php71w-intl php71w-mbstring php71w-mcrypt php71w-mysqlnd php71w-opcache php71w-pdo php71w-pear php71w-pecl-apcu php71w-pecl-imagick php71w-pgsql php71w-process php71w-pspell php71w-recode php71w-soap php71w-tidy php71w-xml

RUN php -v
```

**Error:**

```
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libX11-common.noarch 0:1.6.7-3.el7_9 will be installed
---> Package libxcb.x86_64 0:1.13-1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libXau.so.6()(64bit) for package: libxcb-1.13-1.el7.x86_64
---> Package php71w-pecl-imagick.x86_64 0:3.4.3-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit) for package: php71w-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit) for package: php71w-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.w7.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package libXau.x86_64 0:1.0.8-2.1.el7 will be installed
---> Package php71w-pecl-imagick.x86_64 0:3.4.3-1.w7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit) for package: php71w-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.w7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit) for package: php71w-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.w7.x86_64
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: php71w-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libMagickWand.so.5()(64bit)
Error: Package: php71w-pecl-imagick-3.4.3-1.w7.x86_64 (webtatic)
           Requires: libMagickCore.so.5()(64bit)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
ERROR: Service 'laravel-env' failed to build : The command '/bin/sh -c yum -y install php71w php71w-bcmath php71w-cli php71w-common php71w-curl php71w-fpm php71w-gd php71w-ldap php71w-imap php71w-intl php71w-mbstring php71w-mcrypt php71w-mysqlnd php71w-opcache php71w-pdo php71w-pear php71w-pecl-apcu php71w-pecl-imagick php71w-pgsql php71w-process php71w-pspell php71w-recode php71w-soap php71w-tidy php71w-xml' returned a non-zero code: 1
```

any idea on whats going on and what went wrong? Am i missing any configurations in dockerFile?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to install php 7.1 from "**webtatic**" (php71w* packages)

This repository is dead, unmaintained (last change in 2019), and broken for recent changes in CentOS, such as the IMageMagick rebase.

> RUN yum-config-manager --enable remi-php71

To properly install PHP from "**remi**" repository, please follow the [wizard instructions](https://rpms.remirepo.net/wizard/)

so, something like

```
RUN yum -y install php php-bcmath php-cli php-common php-curl php-fpm php-gd php-ldap php-imap php-intl php-mbstring php-mcrypt php-mysqlnd php-opcache php-pdo php-pear php-pecl-apcu php-pecl-imagick php-pgsql php-process php-pspell php-recode php-soap php-tidy php-xml
```

Notice: you don't need both "php" (mod_php for apache) and "php-fpm" (FPM service for any web server)

**NOTICE** PHP 7.1 have reach its [end of life](https://www.php.net/eol.php) in December 2019, and even if "remi" repository provided some minimal security fixes, I heartily recommend updating to a supported version.